# Rearrange Buttons on Tinymce

Tags: extjs, tinymce

I have an old project with tinymce implemented in it using extjs. I just would like to rearrange the buttons inside tinymce as shown in the picture below. I just need to bring the paste icons from 2nd row to top row

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The data for how TinyMCE is configured is in a configuration that is used when calling `tinymce.init()`.

When you find the configuration object that is being passed you will find a set of data tied to the toolbars and what buttons appear on what row of the toolbars.

There are a variety of options so it is hard to say exactly what you will find but it could look like this:

```
tinymce.init({
  toolbar1: "undo redo | styleselect | bold italic",
  toolbar2: "link image"
});
```

...or...

```
tinyMCE.init({
  theme_advanced_buttons1 : "separator,insertdate,inserttime,preview,zoom...",
  theme_advanced_buttons2 :  "bullist,numlist,separator,outdent,indent...",
  theme_advanced_buttons3 : "hr,removeformat,visualaid..."
});
```